# Constructing Feynman diagrams from Lagrangians containing $\partial\phi$ and no $g$'s

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams

Let $L=L_0+L_1$, $L_0=-\frac{1}{2}(\partial \phi)^2-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$ and $L_1=-2\lambda\phi(\partial\phi)^2-\alpha m^2\phi^3-2\lambda^2\phi^2(\partial\phi)^2-\beta m^2\phi^4$. Find the scattering amplitude of the $\phi\phi\to\phi\phi$ process. Here $m,\alpha,\beta,\lambda$ are constants.

My questions are:

1. What is $\partial\phi$? I've only seen lagrangians with $\phi$ before.
2. The way that I understood this was that $L_0$ is always of order $0$ in $g$, and $L_1$ is written as terms of order $g$ + counter terms of higher orders of $g$. Hence, we could split up the lagrangian in orders of $g$. Here, there seem to be no $g$'s at all. Hence should I consider all terms of $L_1$ in my Feynman diagrams?

Comment: @Oбжорoв- I know what derivatives are. I'm a non-physicist taking QFT, so apologies if my questions sound stupid. I also know that $\lambda,\alpha,\beta$ are letters like $g$. However, the example in my QFT book expands the lagrangian in terms of $g$. and then ignores higher order terms of $g$- in effect, it constructs diagrams only for first order in $g$. Should I construct examples here in first order of all of $\alpha,\beta,\lambda$ and ignore the $\lambda^2$ term?

Comment: @Oбжорoв- Also, I suppose my question is what effect does $\partial\phi$ have on a Feynman diagram as opposed to $\phi$?

Answer (score 0):

The $(\partial\phi)^2$ will give you the momentum dependence in the propagator, $\sim 1/(p^2+m^2)$. Just as you can expand in $g$ you can as well expand in the other parameters $\lambda, \alpha$ and $\beta$.

But in all honesty, if these are really questions you have, then trying to learn QFT seems a bit ambitious to say the least and I would suggest you to start with something simpler.